# Connecting with Camel to outlook.office365.com with IMAP protocol

Tags: azure-active-directory, apache-camel, office365

I'm trying to connect to outlook.office365.com with Apache Camel. I was following instructions for camel component "Mail Microsoft Oauth"

On Azure side I created "App registration" and in my code I use "Application (client) ID" from that registration as client_id, and "Directory (tenant) ID" as tenant_id.
Then I created client secret for that registration and I use "value" as client_secret.

Last I granted API permission "IMAP.AccessAsApp" and granted Admin consent.

In Java I have configured MicrosoftExchangeOnlineOAuth2MailAuthenticator

```
  @Bean
  public MicrosoftExchangeOnlineOAuth2MailAuthenticator auth() {
    return new MicrosoftExchangeOnlineOAuth2MailAuthenticator(
        <tenant_id>,
        <client_id>,
        <client_secret>, "valid@email.com");
  }
```

and Camel route

```
public class MailListenerRoute extends RouteBuilder {

  @Override
  public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("imaps://outlook.office365.com:993"
        +  "?authenticator=#auth"
        +  "&username=valid@email.com"
        +  "&mail.imaps.auth.mechanisms=XOAUTH2"
        +  "&mail.imap.auth.plain.disable=true"
        +  "&mail.imap.auth.xoauth2.disable=false"
        +  "&debugMode=true"
        +  "&delete=false")
        .tracing()
        .log(">>> ${body}");
  }
}
```

I have experimented with both putting and removing, `username`, `mail.imap.auth.plain.disable` and `mail.imap.auth.xoauth2.disable` but there was no changes in result.
I have put debug point at MicrosoftExchangeOnlineOAuth2MailAuthenticator and I have decoded JWT token that is received at method getPasswordAuthentication and I have confirmed by decoding it at JWT.ms that it is valid and that it contains

```
  "roles": [
    "IMAP.AccessAsApp"
  ]
```

When starting a flow this is logs for mail component:

```
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2 command trace suppressed
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2 command result: B1 NO AUTHENTICATE failed.
2023-07-03 10:03:34.206  WARN 16471 --- [fice365.com:993] o.a.camel.component.mail.MailConsumer    : Failed polling endpoint: imaps://outlook.office365.com:993?authenticator=%23auth&debugMode=true&delete=false&mail.imaps.auth.mechanisms=XOAUTH2&username=xxxxxx. Will try again at next poll. Caused by: [javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException - AUTHENTICATE failed.]

javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: AUTHENTICATE failed.
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:708) ~[jakarta.mail-1.6.7.jar:1.6.7]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by following instructions to [set Service Principle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth#register-service-principals-in-exchange)

I had to run commands in Windows Powers Shell because command `Connect-ExchangeOnline -Organization <tenantId>` was failing in Azure power shell with  message `Connect-ExchangeOnline: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Organization`

I have run Windows Shell on AWS EC2 machine because I had no Windows available, and there was no problems.

All commands I have executed in Windows Shell:

```
Install-Module -Name ExchangeOnlineManagement -allowprerelease
Import-module ExchangeOnlineManagement 
Connect-ExchangeOnline -Organization <tenantId>

$AADServicePrincipalDetails = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -SearchString YourAppName

New-ServicePrincipal -AppId $AADServicePrincipalDetails.AppId -ObjectId $AADServicePrincipalDetails.ObjectId -DisplayName "EXO Serviceprincipal for AzureAD App $($AADServicePrincipalDetails.Displayname)"

$EXOServicePrincipal = Get-ServicePrincipal -Identity "EXO Serviceprincipal for AzureAD App YourAppName"

Add-MailboxPermission -Identity "valid@email.com" -User $EXOServicePrincipal.Identity -AccessRights FullAccess
```